# Replacing form action dynamically with input value

Tags: jquery, regex, forms, replace

This is an example form for the docs of our API. It allows the developers to display the json results, in this case of the **/v1/get/profile/58** call. Of course, **58** is just a default example value that they need to be able to modify, that's why the form action does not automatically integrate the example integer, and instead, places a **:id_user** string that serves as a token that would be easy to replace.

The issue that im having, is that there are lots of forms (at least 20) and the search and replacement should be executed with a regex.

```
<form action="/v1/get/profile/:id_user" method="GET" />
    <input name="id_user" id="id_user" value="58" /> User ID
    <input name="id_city" id="id_city" value="185" /> City ID
    <button type="submit">submit data</button>
</form>
```

Observation, we do also have forms that have actions without dynamic calls. Example:

```
    <form action="/v1/get/cities" method="GET" />
```

This is what i've tried so far, but im kind of lost in the regex implementation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        if(regex-condition-is-found) { //pseudo-code for example purposes
            $(this).attr('action',this.attr('action').replace(:regex-needle, regex-replacement); //pseudo-code for example purposes
            }
    }); 
});
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){

    var action = this.action;

    // replace values in action url for all inputs in the form
    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
        action = action.replace(':'+this.id, this.value);
    });

    this.action = action;

});
```

To make it more generic, you can include, selects and textareas as well though'll hardly ever need to send textarea data through the URL - `$(this).find('input, select')`

And if you are likely to have multiple occurences of a value in your URL, you can replace that `replace()` line with:

```
while(action.indexOf(':'+this.id) !== -1) action = action.replace(':'+this.id, this.value);
```

Comment: This worked out with a few jquery tweaks: `action = action.replace(':' + $(this).attr('name'),$(this).val());`

Answer (score 0):

First give your forms and submit buttons IDs

```
<form id="form_id" action="/v1/get/profile/:id_user" method="GET" />
    <input name="id_user" id="id_user" value="58" /> User ID
    <input name="id_city" id="id_city" value="185" /> City ID
    <button id="submit1_id" type="submit">submit data</button>
</form>
```

Doing something like this will allow you to define as many ajax search functions as you need, each responsive to a different search button by id.

```
function searchOne() {
    var paramStr = $('#form_id').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: './script.cgi',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: paramStr,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            processJSON(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Failed to perform gene search! textStatus: (" + textStatus +
                  ") and errorThrown: (" + errorThrown + ")");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#submit1_id').click( function() {
        searchOne();
        return false; // prevents 'normal' form submission
    });
    $('#submit2_id').click(function() {
        searchTwo();
        return false;  // prevents 'normal' form submission
    });
    $('#submit3_id').click(function() {
        searchThree();
        return false;  // prevents 'normal' form submission
    });
}
```

And then the last thing you would need is a processJSON function that would do something with the data you get back. Though perhaps I'm not understanding exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: actually i was planning on adding a target="_blank" to the form's html tag, so that the script is executed on a different window, that's why i have to replace variables in situ.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it completely with regex, you can just get the HTML of the forms' parent and run that through javascript's `String.replace()` -- it's really simple:

```
var form_parent = document.getElementById('#form-parent'),
    search = /action="\/v1\/get\/profile\/(:id_user|(?:\d+))/g,
    root = 'action="/v1/get/profile';

function change_form_action (uid) {
  var new_html = form_parent.innerHTML.replace(search, root + uid + '"');
  form_parent.innerHTML = new_html;
}
```

This will change the form-action where you match id_user or a userid, skipping form actions that don't take a uid.